# Excel do not print if zero

Tags: excel, vba, display

my actual code is :

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveMailActiveSheetAsPDFIn2016()
    'Ron de Bruin : 1-May-2016
    'Test macro to save/mail the Activesheet as pdf with ExportAsFixedFormat with Mail
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FolderName As String
    Dim Folderstring As String
    Dim FilePathName As String
    Dim strbody As String

    'Check for AppleScriptTask script file that we must use to create the mail
    If CheckAppleScriptTaskExcelScriptFile(ScriptFileName:="RDBMacMail.scpt") = False Then
        MsgBox "Sorry the RDBMacMail.scpt is not in the correct location"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'My example sheet is landscape, I must attach this line
    'for making the PDF also landscape, seems to default to
    'xlPortait the first time you run the code
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape

    'Name of the folder in the Office folder
    FolderName = "TempPDFFolder"
    'Name of the pdf file
    FileName = "Order " & [C1] & " " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy") & ".pdf"

    Folderstring = CreateFolderinMacOffice2016(NameFolder:=FolderName)
    FilePathName = Folderstring & Application.PathSeparator & FileName

    'Create the body text in the strbody string
    strbody = "Hi " & [C2] & "," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Please find attached our new order" & vbNewLine & _
vbNewLine & _
        "Thanks"

    'expression A variable that represents a Workbook, Sheet, Chart, or Range object.
    'Not working if you change activeworkbook, always save the activesheet
    'Also the parameters are not working like in Windows
    ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
    FilePathName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

    'Call the MacExcel2016WithMacMailPDF function to save the new pdf and create the mail
    'When you use more mail addresses separate them with a ,
    'Look in Mail>Preferences for the name of the mail account or signature
    'Account name looks like this : "Your Name <your@mailaddress.com>"
    MacExcel2016WithMacMailPDF subject:=[C6] & Format(Date, "dd/mm/yy"), _
    mailbody:=strbody, _
    toaddress:=[C3], _
    ccaddress:=[C4], _
    bccaddress:=[C5], _
    attachment:=FilePathName, _
    displaymail:=True, _
    thesignature:="", _
    thesender:=""
End Sub
```

I would like that all cells from E column in the print area =0 not to be displayed and that the sheet shrinks itself (like deleting the lines were =0), this before creating the .pdf document and opening mailbox.

I dunno if I'm clear enough sorry

Thank you for your help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming column E of Sheet1 is the one you want to hide if filled with zeros:

```
Sub hideZeroFilledColumn()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E:E")

    rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = (Excel.WorksheetFunction.Count(rng) = _
                                Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "0"))

End Sub
```

Or, if you want to hide just the lines when cell value in column E:E is 0:

```
Sub hideLineWithZero()

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim strColumn As String
    strColumn = "E" 'If the column you want to check is "E:E"

    'Getting first row of printarea and setting "rngPrintStart" to that row in column strColumn
    Dim rngPrintStart As Range
    'The split is used to separate the start and end of the PrintArea address
    'Here we take component "0" of the split, so the start part of the PrintArea
    Set rngPrintStart = Range(Split(WS.PageSetup.PrintArea, ":")(0))
    Set rngPrintStart = WS.Range(strColumn & rngPrintStart.Row)

    'Getting last row of printarea and setting "rngPrintEnd" to that row in column strColumn
    Dim rngPrintEnd As Range
    'The split is used to seperate the start and end of the PrintArea address
    'Here we take component "1" of the split, so the end part of the PrintArea
    Set rngPrintEnd = Range(Split(WS.PageSetup.PrintArea, ":")(1))
    Set rngPrintEnd = WS.Range(strColumn & rngPrintEnd.Row)

    'Merging rngPrintStart and rngPrintEnd ranges from printarea in column strColumn
    Dim rngPrintColumnE As Range
    Set rngPrintColumnE = WS.Range(rngPrintStart, rngPrintEnd)

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngToHide As Range
    'looking in all cells from rngPrintColumnE
    For Each rng In rngPrintColumnE
        'checking if cell value is equal to 0 and is not empty
        If (rng.Value2 = 0) And (rng.Value2 <> "") Then
            'Building the range to be hidden
            If rngToHide Is Nothing Then 'For the first time when "rngToHide" is not yet set
                Set rngToHide = rng
            Else
                Set rngToHide = Union(rngToHide, rng)
            End If
        End If
    Next rng

    'to hide the rows from the previously built range
    rngToHide.Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I want to hide the line corresponding to the zero value in the column (hide all lines with zero result in E)

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you so much for your help guys !

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to hide column E if all the values in it are zero?

Do a sum of the values into another cell (X99 in my example) then use the following code:

```
With ActiveSheet
  If .Range("X99").Value = 0 Then
      .Range("e:e").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  Else
      .Range("e:e").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
  End If
End With
```

Edit:

You can use Abs(Min(E:E))>0 instead of Sum if you have negative values

---

For some reason I can't add another answer so here goes with another edit.

To hide *rows* that have zero in the e column:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim pa As Range

Dim ecolnumber As Integer
ecolnumber = 5

Set pa = Range(ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea)

For i = 0 To pa.Rows.Count

  Dim ecell As Range
  Set ecell = pa(i, ecolnumber)

  ecell.EntireRow.Hidden = ecell.Value = 0   

Next
```

Note the ecolnumber, you may have to change it to reference the correct column.

After you have done all your stuff you can unhide the rows with:

```
For i = 0 To pa.Rows.Count

  Set ecell = pa(i, ecolnumber)

  ecell.EntireRow.Hidden = False

Next
```

Comment: If there is the possibility of having negative and positive values this will not be full proof.

Comment: @simpLE MAn That'll be _fool proof_ then, none of us are perfect :-)

Comment: Thank you, I want to hide the line corresponding to the zero value in the column (hide all lines with zero result in E)

Comment: You want to hide the **row**?

Comment: Yes, fro example let's take E4 = 0, I want to hide the line 4 when printing. (And if possible, compile the other lines so that there is no "hole" between line 3 and line 5.